# Algorithm: Stop invalid entries into a Competition in python script

Tags: android, python, algorithm, computer-science

I have an Android Mobile App that is really just a calendar & you can click a certain date & a secret code pops up. The user uses that code to enter a competition - they follow the link to the competition HTML page(python script really) & enter their details to enter the competition. There are 100 minor prizes & 3 major prizes. A code can either be a non-winning code or it can win the user a prize(either the minor or major).

So they will be redirected to: http://mycompetition.com/comp.py?code=ABCDEF

Then they enter their age, code & image captcha(avoiding spammers) & click enter competition.

**My Problem:** I am having difficulty coming up with an algorithm to ensure that people just don't type in the above URL & put a random code value for the CGI 'code' value & accidentally win a prize if they guess a correct code(or they use a bot to keep trying).

**Can you come up with any ideas to avoid someone who has not purchased the app just going to the url above & typing in a random code & accidently winning the prize?**

My algorithms/ideas:
- Have the code 12 characters long which makes the probability of guessing the code very slim but still possible. I am bad with maths & probability so if I use 26 char & 10 digits as potential chars in the code does that mean the probability of guesing correct 1 out of (36 chars * 12 pass length * 103 prizes)? Does that probability leave only supercomputers(not that I believe anyones going to devote a super computer to my comp :P) able to guess the code?
- Dont associate a prize with a code. Instead just have the android app randomly generate some code that means nothing & when they enter the competition I just give them a random 1/10000 (I dont expect anywhere near 10000 entries into the comp) of winning a prize. To enter the competition you have to enter your age & the code & then enter a captcha to avoid spammers.
- Is there any easier algorithm you know of that avoids users who haven't purchased the app getting a prize?

**EDIT:**
- What about whenever the App is downloaded I look at their phones(wireless part) MAC address. On 1st run of the app I upload that MAC address to my server that contains a list of MAC addresses of users of my app. When/If they discover the secret code, they clikc enter competition & are redirected to http://mycompetition.com/comp.py?code=RANDOMMEANINGLESSGENERATEDCODE&uniqueID=USERSMACADDRESS. In my script I check that the uniqueID is in my list of users who downloaded my app, if it isn't I dont proceed, if it is they have 1/10000 chance of winning a prize. Can you see any flaws in this algorithm?

Comment: Successful methods must reduce the velocity of incoming guesses/entries so someone can't just brute-force all the prizes.  If you're only giving out so many codes, you might simply have a global throttle (tho that make you vulnerable to DoS)...

Comment: Global Throttle? What is that? Would I still be vulnerable to Denial of Service attacks if to enter the competition you have to enter a captcha?

Comment: Global throttle would mean that your web server limits the numbers of entries per unit time.  Good point about the captcha.  Missed that.  Be careful of your captcha selection, tho.  Some can be automated, and if people care enough (probably won't), they can farm out a captcha.  Sounds like you should just increase the number of bits in your code.  If there is some way to pass unique verifiable data (e.g. e-mail address), it could help to add that too.  The 1/10000 doesn't make sense.  You have X prizes, and Y entrants, and neither number is really related to 10000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) to generate the code based on a secret you share between the Android app and the site. As the text for the HMAC, you can use a random value, which you include in the resulting code, or something unique to the user, such as their email address (meaning that each user can only have one valid code). If the length of the code is important, you can truncate the hash produced by the HMAC, but bear in mind that the shorter you truncate it, the more practical a brute-force attack is.

As long as your users cannot discover the shared secret, this will be secure insofar as an attacker would have to guess at random, or attempt to determine the secret by brute force. Since the code runs on user-owned devices, though, there's no way to prevent them from extracting the code from your app. A user with a rooted phone and a disassembler could do this relatively easily. To combat that, you could obfuscate the code, and release new versions of the app, updating the secret key there and on the site, whenever you suspect it's been compromised.

Ultimately, because the device is in the user's control, there's no way to totally prevent users from generating their own codes, but using an approach such as the one above, you can make it much more difficult for them, and easier for you to recover from it.